# How to get an unquoted/expanded parameter’s value inside a macro

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I need to get an access to the real value of `@attr` inside a call to `A.target`

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro target(param) do
    IO.inspect param, label: "Inside a macro"
  end
end

defmodule B do
  @attr 42
  require A
  A.target(@attr)
end
```

I surely have

```
Inside a macro: {:@, [line: 10], [{:attr, [line: 10], nil}]}
```

printed, because at this very moment the AST is being built, and `A.target/1` is not responsible for expanding its parameters. I see that I might get an access to the value of parameter, rather than to it’s AST within `quote do` block:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro target(param) do
    quote do: IO.inspect uquote(param), label: "unquote"
  end
end
```

The thing is I need the value to be expanded upfront. What I have tried:

- `var!`
- `Macro.expand`
- any variation of `Code.eval`

So, my question would be: **is it possible to force-expand macro parameter in the very first line of macro body**?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. Outside the quote block in your macro, @attr does not have a value. Its just a quoted expression. Module B has not been compiled yet. You can only access @attr inside the quote block of A, since its executed in the context of B.

Comment: That sounds reasonable and my first guess was exactly this. On the other hand, it should be possible to _defer_ an expansion of the AST to permit e.g. iterating on parameters passed to the macro / building the resulting AST based on some not yet expanded configuration.

Comment: You could, but its only going to be valid when you unquote it inside the quote block of the macro. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to provide a pull request to the library that passes unquoted values through a set of macros. I just was trying to minimize the size of this PR, by not touching the existing code, but it seems it’s just impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the question; new to writing elixir macros.

I do not recommended programming this way, but this was a fun exercise!

It looks like your question is regarding using a constant @attr.

That was a major pain point for this question!

Definitely a hack  but you can convert do this with two changes.

1) Convert the tuple from the macro to a list.

2) attr in the macro does not play nice so you need to change it to a str.

specific to number two here was the error that reoccured with eval even if you call within the module it probably is reaching out to some macro module.

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot invoke @/1 outside module
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:5212: Kernel.assert_module_scope/3
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.@/1
    nofile:11: (file)
    expanding macro: A.target/1
    try.exs:11: B (module)
```

With some smart maneuverings manipulate the values to do whatever you want just make sure to transform the list back into a tuple And the "attr" into {attr} before you unquote.

**Solution:**

```
defmodule A do
  def foo( {item1, item2, [ {item4, item5, item6} ] } ) do
    [item1, item2, "#{item4}", item5, item6]
  end
  defmacro target(param) do
    macroModified =  param |> foo()
    quote do
      param = unquote(param)
      macroModified  = unquote(macroModified )

      IO.inspect [result: param, macro: [macroModified ]]
    end
  end
end

defmodule B do
  @attr 42
  require A
  A.target(@attr)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this what you want?

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro target(param) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect unquote(param), label: "Inside a macro"
    end
  end
end

defmodule B do
  @attr 42
  require A
  A.target(@attr)
end
```

A macro receives quoted arguments. To get the actual value, you have to unquote it. You can unquote an argument only inside quote block.

When a macro returns a quoted expression, it is inserted inside the calling module and run, so know that the `IO.inspect...` is running inside `B` module.

Comment: This does not have access to `@attr` inside the macro. This only has access to `@attr` in the module body of `B` at `B`'s compile time(after macro expansion). Not at the time the macro is expanded. You can confirm that by putting an inspect between the `defmacro` and `quote` lines of module `A`. You'll see `{:@, [line: 7], [{:attr, [line: 7], nil}]}`